# Discord.js: Check if message is deleted

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

This is how my bot fetches messages:

```
await channel.messages.fetch(snowflake)
```

These are the following behaviors I've observed:

- If the message exists in the channel and this is called, this returns a `Message` object with the snowflake ID.
- **If the message is deleted while the bot is on and this is called, this *still* returns a `Message` object with the snowflake ID**, likely the same object from cache.
- If the message is deleted when the bot is off and this is called after the bot turns on, this raises a `DiscordAPIError` with code `10008`.
- If the message is deleted when the bot is on, then the bot is restarted, then this is called, this also raises the same `DiscordAPIError` previously.

The bolded case unfortunately makes it hard for me to check if the message is deleted or not. It doesn't raise the same `DiscordAPIError` and because of that the code goes along nicely until I do operations on the `Message` object such as `.delete` or `.edit` which will raise the `DiscordAPIError`.

The problem with `try...catch`ing the `.delete`, `.edit`, etc. functions is that I would have to do this for *every* one of those functions, which is not what I want. **I want to be able to stop the code before it reaches to those operations by checking if the message is deleted or not**, either by `try...catch` or `if`.

No, `.deleted` is deprecated and unfortunately I can't use this.

Unfortunately `.editable` doesn't update when the message is deleted while the bot is on.

**How would I detect if a message is deleted using `channel.messages.fetch` before performing operations on it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the force option with fetch to skip the cache check

```js
await channel.messages.fetch({ message: snowflake, force: true })
```